# IPC using NSConnection on OS X 10.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, ipc, mach

I've developed two apps which communicate between each other using IPC.
Here is a code of server and client sides:

Server:

```
_distantObject = [[DistantObject alloc] init];
        
NSPort *serverPort = [NSMachPort port];
_proxyConnection = [[NSConnection alloc] initWithReceivePort:serverPort sendPort:serverPort];
[_proxyConnection setRootObject:_distantObject];
        
if (![_proxyConnection registerName:@"MyServer"]) {
            
   NSLog(@"ERROR: starting MyServer");
}
```

Client:

```
    DistantObject *remoteObject;
    NSConnection *theConnection = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"MyServer"
                                                                        host:nil];
    if (theConnection != nil) {
        
        remoteObject = (DistantObject *)[theConnection rootProxy];
        remoteObject.someValue = value;
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work on OS X 10.6. But works perfectly on 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9.
Here is an errors I receive on 10.6:

> __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10031a0f0 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
> __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100330b50 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

As result client doesn't pass appropriated value.

Comment: Have you tried sticking `@autoreleasepool { ... }` around the code?

Comment: Yes. My server's and client code is wrapped with autoreleasepool